# Корректность фразы «с гор сыплется грунт»

Tags: лексика, семантика

Грунт — любая горная порода, почва, осадок и техногенные минеральные образования.
С учётом этого значения можно ли сказать: *с гор осыпается/сползает грунт*?

Comment: Проблема в том, что грунт входит в состав горы? Или вопрос в том, может ли грунт осыпаться и сползать?

Comment: Может ли грунт осыпаться?

Comment: В словарях сказано о растениях, но оно и в других случаях используется. Звучит нормально.

Comment: О каких растениях сказано в словарях. Я не совсем понял.

Comment: Лишиться листвы, лепестков, зёрен и т.п. (о растениях). *Берёза осыпала свою листву.*

Comment: А-а, вы о глаголе "осыпаться" говорите.

Comment: Лишиться листвы, лепестков и т.п. *Цветы осыпались. В октябре акации почти осыпались. Перезревшая пшеница осыпалась.*

Comment: Первое было о "осыпать".

Comment: Необязательно. Осыпаться— Высыпаться, отделившись откуда нибудь.

Comment: То о "о**т**сыпаться") Нормальная фраза, если бы не эти консервативные словари, то можно было бы с уверенностью сказать, что здесь всё в порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Происходит осыпание *комьев*, *глыб*, *участков* грунта. Грунт практически не бывает однороден и плотен в своей массе.

> Наконец, если мы обратимся к древним ледниковым наносам, например
> Норвегии, Швеции и Финляндии, то мы увидим, что слоистость в
> ледниковом щебне попадается беспрестанно, и мне остается только
> сослаться на Чьерульфа для Норвегии, на геологическую съемку для
> Швеции и на приведенные в I части книги примеры для Финляндии, где
> упомянуты также и другие возможные причины слоеватости щебня
> (сползание полужидких масс, осыпание). [П. А. Кропоткин. Главы из
> неопубликованного 2-го выпуска книги «Исследования о ледниковом
> периоде» (1874-1876)]